# How to create expanded listview using java script?

Tags: javascript, expandablelistview

i want to create vertical expandable list view using java script.like [here click](http://www.udm4.com/demos/expanding-single.php).If anyone knows guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you're looking to build a menu system?

Comment: Yes fluidbyte as same as above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple one I built awhile back (requires jQuery).

http://www.fluidbyte.net/simple-jquery-expandcollapse-unordered-lists

It's fairly simple to customize and implement.

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery it's pretty simple, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/RGc36/5/